# Check filetype Javascript array for extension then do something

Tags: javascript

Using vanilla javascript(no jQuery), I'd like to search an array and check if an extension exists. I've got this far using `indexOf` but all file extensions are showing as in the array when they're clearly not.

I'm pretty sure my logic is off somehow, but I'll be damned if I know why!

The file is coming from a `<input type="file">` choose file mechanism, hence the `fileChosen` part.

Cheers,

```
const actualBtn = document.getElementById('userfile');

const fileChosen = document.getElementById('file-chosen');

const filetypes = ('pdf','doc','docx');

actualBtn.addEventListener('change', function(){
    fileChosen.textContent = this.files[0].name;
    let fileName = this.files[0].name;
    let extension = fileName.split(".").pop();

    if(filetypes.indexOf(extension) < 0) {
        console.log(extension);
    }
});
```

Comment: `filetypes.indexOf(extension) < 0`: if an extension _doesn't_ exist in the array log it to the console. If you want to log extensions that _are_ in the array you want `filetypes.indexOf(extension) >= 0` or `filetypes.includes(extension)`.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I'm seeing both behaviours at once with this code. It's logging whatever file extension happens to be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the logic was fine but my array was wrong. I changed the array to this and suddenly the logic kicked in and everything worked.

`var filetypes = ["pdf","doc","docx"];`